# Limit of the ratio of two areas

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

**The Question**
An arc $PQ$ of a circle subtends a central angle $\theta$ as in the figure. Let $A(\theta)$ be the area between the chord $PQ$ and the arc $PQ$. Let $B(\theta)$ be the area between the tangent lines $PR$, $QR$, and the arc.

Find:
$$\lim_{\theta\to0^+}{\frac{A(\theta)}{B(\theta)}}$$

[image]

**What I've done**
I have been able to show that
$$\lim_{\theta\to0^+}{\frac{A(\theta)}{B(\theta)}}=\frac{1}{\lim_{\theta\to0^+}{\frac{(1-\cos\theta)\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta)-\sin^2\theta}}{(\theta-\sin\theta)\sin\theta}}-1}$$
and using a computer algebra system, I got the answer 2. But I do not know how the computer got the answer and searching the web did not help at all. Can someone that knows give an answer?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my calculations, giving a different formula but the same limit $2$.

Let us assume, without loss of generality, that the radius of the circle is $1$.

Let $\alpha = \frac12 \theta$:

$$\begin{cases}\text{Using area of triangle } OPQ: & A(\theta)&=&\alpha - \sin \alpha \cos \alpha\\ \text{Using area of triangle } OPR: &A(\theta)+B(\theta)&=&\tan \alpha - \sin \alpha \cos \alpha \end{cases}$$ giving

$$B(\theta)=\tan \alpha - \alpha$$

Therefore :

$$\lim_{\theta \to 0^+}\frac{A(\theta)}{B(\theta)}=\lim_{\alpha \to 0^+}\frac{\alpha - \sin \alpha \cos \alpha}{\tan \alpha - \alpha}=\lim_{\alpha \to 0^+}\frac{\alpha -(\alpha - \tfrac16 \alpha^3+\cdots)(1-\tfrac12\alpha^2+\cdots)}{(\alpha+\tfrac13\alpha^3-\cdots) - \alpha}$$

(using Taylor expansions) ; as the numerator is $\approx \frac23\alpha^3$, the denominator is $\approx \frac13\alpha^3$, the limit is equal to $2$.

Comment: Thank for the answer! By the way, you can evaluate the limit using L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @MathIsFun You are right : L'Hôpital's rule would give also the answer. But please note there are subtle cases where L'Hôpital's rule needs conditions, whereas using MacLaurin series is always "secure".